# Ignore the require statement on webpack 2 bundling time and exclude that require statement from the bundled js

Tags: webpack-2

I implement a `React.Component` in `a.js`. This file will be used for client and server side rendering. Of course `a.js` has `require("a.scss")`

Is there a way to do on `webpack.config.js` only to tell webpack not to read all the scss` require statement during the bundling?

I did try the `IgnorePlugin` to `*.scss`. The bundling process is fine but `node` gives runtime error which is `Cannot find module './a.scss'`

Here are the unwanted suggestions

- I don't want to use `DefinePlugin` or `EnvironmentPlugin` because I don't want to wrap the `require("a.scss")` inside an `if` statement
- I don't want to use `ExtractTextWebpackPlugin` to extract the `scss` which is I am currently using. Let `node` can run the bundled `js` perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution

```
{
  "test": /\.s?css$/,
  "use": "null-loader"
}
```